# How to specify numShards and shardIndex for Android instrumentation tests?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

$ gradlew connectedCheck -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=5

```
> Configure project :app
Passing custom test runner argument android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards from gradle.properties or command line is not compatible with configuration caching. Please specify this argument using android gradle dsl.
```

I wonder what that magical "android gradle dsl" is. Usually there's a link to documentation in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

So what I figured is that `-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.xxx=yyy` (or equivalently defined in gradle.properties) is a magical property that's populating the DSL like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.put("xxx", "yyy")
    }
}
```